# Show/Hide portfolio items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Thanks for your answers and sorry forgot to post HTML of categories I want to display! -

It's in Wordpress, so clicking the ul li#digi shows the digital categories - just think the jquery could be simplified..

```
<div class="post-12 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish hentry category-digital">
<h3>Ogilvie Homes</h3>
</div>
<div class="post-13 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish hentry category-audio">
<h3>BBC News</h3>
</div>
```

etc etc

So to confirm clicking  the li# would show the corresponding divs as above..

```
<div class="filter group">
    <ul>
        <li id="all">All</li>
        <li id="digi">Digital</li>
        <li id="social">Social Media</li>
        <li id="print">Print</li>
        <li id="aud">Audio</li>
        <li id="pub">PR</li>
        <li id="cm">Content Marketing</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

//jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#all").click(function() {
$(".category-digital").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-print").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").show("fast", "linear");
}), 

$("#digi").click(function() {
$(".category-digital").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-print").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").hide("fast", "linear");
})

$("#social").click(function() {
$(".category-social-media").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").hide("fast", "linear");    
$(".category-print").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-digital").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").hide("fast", "linear");
})

$("#print").click(function() {
$(".category-print").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-digital").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").hide("fast", "linear");
})

$("#aud").click(function() {
$(".category-audio").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-print").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-digital").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").hide("fast", "linear");
})

$("#pub").click(function() {
$(".category-pr").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-print").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-digital").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-content-marketing").hide("fast", "linear");
})

$("#cm").click(function() {
$(".category-content-marketing").show("fast", "linear");
$(".category-social-media").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-print").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-digital").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-pr").hide("fast", "linear");
$(".category-audio").hide("fast", "linear");

})
});
```

Comment: html of `category-*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this: I've changed the ids so they fit to the -category titles.

```
    <div class="filter group">

    <ul>
        <li id="all">All</li>

        <li id="digital">Digital</li>

        <li id="social-media">Social Media</li>

        <li id="print">Print</li>

        <li id="audio">Audio</li>

        <li id="pr">PR</li>

        <li id="content-marketing">Content Marketing</li>
    </ul>

   </div>
```

and than use the following js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.li').click(function () {
        $('[class^=category-]').hide('fast','linear');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id == 'all') {
             $('[class^=category-]').show('fast','linear');
        } else {
             $('.category-'+id).show('fast','linear');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited my post above.

Comment: I think you misread the question, it's not about hiding of showing the filter li items. It's about using the li items to filter another elements marked with a category class.

Comment: @frikinside : Thanks for the hint! I have edited my code. Should match the question now.

Comment: No problem! And yes, I think it match the question now, unless the mistaken was me the whole time! But, just one thing, in your answer you use the containing substring selector, it would be better if you use the starts with, replacing the $('[class*=category-]') with $('[class^=category-]').

Comment: Ok, cool! Thanks for the tip! I'm always using *= so didn't thought about another one, but you're right, ^= would be better here! - Edited it ;)

Comment: Thanks you so much that worked a treat - just to let you know the class didn't being with "category-" so I ditched $('[class^=category-]'). and used $('[class*=category-]') as it's wordpress and it throws in random classes!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".filter ul li").click(function(){
  $(".filter ul li").hide();
  $(this).show("fast", "linear");
 });
```

Comment: I think you misread the question, it's not about hiding of showing the filter li items. It's about using the li items to filter another elements marked with a category class.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide all categories and show the one you clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".filter ul li").click(function() {
    $(".filter ul li").hide("fast", "linear"); 
    $(this).show("fast", "linear"); 
}) 

});
```

Comment: I think you misread the question, it's not about hiding of showing the filter li items. It's about using the li items to filter another elements marked with a category class.

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide everything with hide(); after which you show the clicked element.

```
$("yourlement").click(function(){
  $("yourelement").hide();
  $(this).show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this as your script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.filter>ul>li').click(function() {
        $('div.filter>ul>li').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you misread the question, it's not about hiding of showing the filter li items. It's about using the li items to filter another elements marked with a category class.

Comment: Hi @frikinside **I'm trying to show a specific category when clicked and hide the others e.g. when #digi is clicked it shows digital and hides the rest **
 - is exactly what i've answered... if he wants category classed items shown/hidden he'll need to update the amount of HTML he's provided.

Comment: Hi @JFit you made a point, and you're right, maybe he must provide more HTML including the classed category items, but I think that the jquery code that shows it's clear enought showing what he wants, but maybe I'm the wrong one and the question is not quite clear.

Comment: I assumed that his content was within the LI cos of the html he gave and the description. but if he provides the HTML it will be handy enough to update that.

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide everything with hide(); after which you show the clicked element.

```
$("your_element").click(function(){
  $("your_element").hide();
  $(this).show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a few changes in the HTML, I think I could provide a simple way to do this in 3 steps.

Step 1)
Change the id of you `li` items for a complete category (`digi` would be `digital`, `aud` would be `audio`,...)

Step 2)
Add to every category wrapper another class `category-all`. So for example, the .category-audio elements now would had another class `category-all`.

Step 3)
Replace you jquery method by this one:

```
$("div.filter.group ul li").click(function(){
    $(".category-all").hide("fast", "linear");
    $(".category-" + this.id).show("fast", "linear");
});
```